# Discord Self-Bots problem to host your code with replit, like finding a place to host my code for 24/7

Tags: service, discord, bots, hosting, host

How can we host our discord self-bots after **replit update**!
like we all know that discord banned replit from making self-bots, so what's the next solution for hosting a discord self-bot, also github has officially announced this condition. SO, please help out guyz!

Expecting a hosting platform like replit to discord self-bots!